# Using array constants in excel vba function

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function in VBA of the type

```
Function MyFunc(Indx As Integer, k As Long, Rho As Range, A As Range) As Variant
....
End Function
```

which is called as a user-defined function from within the Excel worksheet. When called with the last two arguments being a range

> Result = MyFunc(1,98,A1:A2, B1:B2))

it works fine. However, when I try to directly use an array constant instead of a range

> Result = MyFunc(1,98,{10,11}, {20,30})

it returns a #VALUE error.

I thought I could fix it by redefining the last two arguments as arrays of type double, but this didn't work either

```
Function MyFunc(Indx As Integer, k As Long, Rho() As Double, A() As Double) As Variant
....
End Function
```

Does someone have a suggestion for a *flexible* solution, which would permit either calling method: by range, as well as by an array constant?

Comment: Are there any built-in functions that allow either a range or array constant as arguments?  In fact, are there any built-in functions that even just allow array constants?  (I thought there was, but all the ones that I have checked are actually using parameter list arrays instead)

Answer (score 3):

You could declare your two parameters as Variant types, then in your function check what has been passed to them using the TypeName(varname) function.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could convert your array in a range object while calling the function.

Result = MyFunc(1,98,Range(10,11), Range(20,30))

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've just tried this, and unfortunately, it fails.